# Hibernate ManyToOne Without Foreign Key

Tags: hibernate

I'm looking for some advice regarding mapping of a large legacy schema.

Here's the situation. Suppose we have a class, called BusinessTransaction. This class has several fields referencing user ids:

```
@Entity
public class BusinessTransaction implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private User createdBy;
    private User editedBy;
    private User cancelledBy;

    private String department;
    // etc 

}

public class User implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String department;
    //etc
}
```

However, there are no foreign keys between the BusinessTransaction table and the User table. In SQL, the User would be connected to the BusinessTransaction via a left outer join on the department key.

Creation of these foreign keys would require the creation of Join Tables. Our DBA is reluctant to create either the Foreign Keys or the join tables, and has understandable reasons for doing so (affecting batch scripts, possible side effects on the app, etc).

The only other idea I had was the use of a JoinFormula. However, @JoinFormula doesn't have the best documentation out there, and my understanding is that the data will be read-only.

Am I overlooking anything that would be useful?

EDIT: Added department.

Jason

Comment: How does a business transaction refer to a user in database if there is no FK? What is stored in the business transaction table to refer to the user?

Comment: My bad. I edited the above, but basically there is a field that a SQL/HQL query could perform a left outer join on.

Comment: a "field so the query could perfom a join" is a foreign key, yet you say you have no foreign key? If the user is identified by department, why not designate the department the primary key of User?

Comment: The id of User id type Long, which is pretty much set in stone (see my explanation about schema changes). Each of those fields in BusinessTransaction could represent the same or a different User. In the current version of the app, each of those fields would be populated via a separate query. I want to know if Hibernate can do it for me, within the limitations I'm stuck with.

Comment: So it is an n-to-m relation, where all transaction with the same department join to the users with the same department?

Comment: Stefan: That is correct.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to create neither foreign keys nor join tables in order to declare the relation between this tables in Hibernate. Hibernate does not verify, if such foreign keys exist (as long as you don't requre database schema validation).

But, note, you'll need proper index on User table. Indices are independent from foreign keys as well, but failing to create them will result in drastic performance loss.

But you must note, in case no foreign keys are created, if the keys in User table are missing, you can expect indeterminate behaviour from Hibernate's side (an error). Foreign keys are for assuring the consistency of the database.